# How to implement update oneToOne in React-JSX-highstock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

How do I implement update oneToOne in the `<Chart/>` component via React-JSX-highstock? There isn't anything in the react-jsx-highcharts docs. Is it something like:

```
<Chart update='oneToOne'/>
```

or

```
<Chart oneToOne />
```

etc...

Comment: Hi @Jason Y, I recommend you to use the officially supported Highcharts wrapper for React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Well I can't just switch. This is widespread at where I work. Also, this doesn't answer the question.